# How expensive are QPainter::save() and QPainter::restore()?

Tags: qt, qpainter, scenegraph

I want to build a scene graph to store and manage my scene layout which will be painted using `QPainter` (like `QPicture`, but the layout should be modifiable).

The scene graph will contain nodes for transformations, clipping and primitives. The first two will need to store the current state of the painter to restore it afterwards. It seems natural to use `QPainter::save()` and `QPainter::restore()` respectively.

I am a bit concerned about the efficiency of these two functions. Qt's documentation gives no information here. Looking at Qt's source code, it seems 
 `QPainter::save()` copies every element of the state, e.g. the pen, the brush, the transformation, the clipping path, and many many more. It seems to me that storing the former state of the one or two relevant properties that I actually need by myself is far more efficient. Has anyone any experience with this?

Comment: If looking at the source isn't helpful, then you could do benchmarking. `QElapsedTimer` around a loop which does a million saves and restores should give some clue, especially if you do other loop which does something else (like draws a line) a million times and compare. My hunch is, save and restore are trivial operations compared to anything else you might do, but that's just a wild guess.

Comment: I never had problems with the mentioned functions with regards to performance. Where your concerns come from? Have you noticed something or what?

Comment: @vahancho My concern is mostly a result of looking at the source, and I did it because of general curiosity. Probably I am very susceptible for premature optimization.